# angularjs component method binding undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component with a method/callback (&) binding, but when I call it, it says it is undefined.

*component*

```
angular
    .module('sportPicker')
    .component('sportPicker', {
        template: template,
        controller: 'sportPickerController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindings: {
            selectSport: '&',
        }
    });
```

*component controller*

```
angular
    .module('sportPicker')
    .controller('sportPickerController', sportPickerController);

sportPickerController.$inject = ['$scope','sportsFactory'];

function sportPickerController($scope, sportsFactory) {
    let vm = this;
    vm.sports = sportsFactory.sports;
    vm.sendSportData = sendSportData;

    vm.$onInit = onInit;

    function onInit() {
        console.log(vm)
        vm.selected_sport = '<select a sport>';
    }

    function sendSportData(sport) {
        vm.selected_sport = sport.display;
        vm.selectSport()(sport);
    }
}
```

*component html*

```
<ul class="sport-picker dropdown-menu-list" role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-menu-sublist-title" role="menuitem">Team</li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu-sublist" role="menu">
            <li ng-repeat='sport in vm.sports.team' role="menuitem" ng-model='vm.selected_sport' ng-click='vm.sendSportData(sport)'><a href="#">{{sport.display}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

*use in app html*
`<sport-picker select-sport='vm.setSport'></sport-picker>`

setSport is defined in the view's controller:

```
function MatchupController(matchupsFactory, $rootScope) {
    let vm = this;
    ...        
    vm.setSport = setSport;
    ...
    function setSport(sport) {
        console.log(sport);
        vm.sport = sport.display;
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in `sportPicker#sendSportData`, I hit that breakpoint, but when it makes the call to `vm.selectSport()(sport)` I get `TypeError: vm.selectSport(...) is not a function` and it never makes it back to the parent element.

I've used the binding like this many times with other components, so I feel like I must be missing something simple and I'm preparing myself for an epic facepalm moment!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an expression binding, I think you need to invoke the function in the HTML:

```
<sport-picker select-sport='vm.setSport()'></sport-picker>
```